# Why does Viz3d::spin() complete without user input?

Tags: opencv, vtk, opencv3.0

I am writing an application that uses opencv's Viz module. My application is essentially as follows:

```
viz::Viz3d myWindow("Reconstruction");
myWindow.spin();
```

When I execute this program, the spin method completes instantaneously. Well, not quite: I see a window flash in front of me before it completes. It is my understanding that the event loop should keep spinning until it detects relevant user input.

I tried restructuring my code, replacing the `spin()` with a while loop:

```
while(!myWindow.wasStopped()) {
   myWindow.spinOnce(1, true);
}
```

As expected, the spinOnce exhibits the same behavior, and completes without displaying any window.

Is this a problem with my installation?